# Angular2 Http.Delete Body is null

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I followed the Angular2 [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) but the Http.delete always throws an exception : 
TypeError: this._body is null

 Original code of hero.service.ts

```
public deleteHero(hero: Hero) {

    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this._http
        .delete(this._heroesUrl + "/" + hero.Id, { headers: headers })
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, while the accepted answer is an effective work-around, the correct solution is to remove the `Content-Type` header.  `DELETE` requests shouldn't have a `body` (empty or otherwise), and so neither should they have a `Content-Type` header.  Same goes for `GET` requests.  The error is thrown as a result of having a `Content-Type` header and no `body` (which is an illogical combination).

Comment: Well I guess I never questioned why there is a content type. Works like a charm without any headers. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the one little thing I was missing was the following:

```
.delete(this._heroesUrl + "/" + hero.Id, { headers: headers, body: "" })
```

after headers: headers you can also set a body. Now since its a delete request there normally is no body. But if body is null angular will throw an exception ...

**EDIT**

This is a workaround but the actual answer is from @simon

Comment: Thanks! After looking through @angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js and manipulating it for null checking there, your solution seems to be way nicer!

Comment: Actually, the correct solution is to remove the `Content-Type` header -- see my answer below.